# What is the difference between the arithmetic operators ^ and .^?

Tags: matlab, operators

What is the difference between the arithmetic operators `^` and `.^` in Matlab ?

Comment: IF any of the answers helped you, consider accepting it: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: Please consider reading MATLAB's help pages before posting basic questions like this.

Answer (score 3):

In Matlab,

Operator `^` is used for the purpose of Matrix Power.
For example let us take matrix A, then `A^B` is A to the power B, if B is a Scalar.For other values of B, the calculation involves eigenvalues and eigenvectors. (you can refer: [mpower](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mpower.html)).

And operator `.^` is used for the purpose of Element-wise power. That is,
`A.^B` is the matrix with elements `A(i,j)` to the `B(i,j)` power. (for more information refer : [power](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/power.html)).

Answer (score 2):

Use `help`: `help ^` and `help .^`.

Or `doc`: `doc ^` and `doc .^`.

`^` refers to [mpower - matrix power](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mpower.html)

`.^` refers to [power - array power/ elementwise power](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/power.html).

Answer (score 0):

Operators preceded by a period act element by element. If you have a matrix A, saying `A^2` returns the square of that matrix (the matrix product A*A), while `A.^2` returns a matrix in which each element is the square of the corresponding element in A.